# Adding PPA on install

Tags: ppa, packaging

I have a app I am packaging for ubuntu.

I don't like the idea that if included in the ubuntu repositories I will have no control over updating that application. I don't want my users stuck on an out dated version for up to 6 months. I also do not want my users to have to manually add a PPA themselves to get updates as the target user will not have the technical know how to do this.

Is it OK to have my .deb add a PPA on install. So that I can roll out stable updates to my ubuntu users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, yes. You can add a ppa with the deb (Google does something similar for example).

Comment: Actually when installing google chrome, google adds 3 ppa-stable, beta, dev for google chrome